# Using OpenSSL library to convert .key encoded to .pem

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, openssl

I created a C program that takes in an encrypted file (`encrypted.key`) file and a public key to decrypt the private encrypted `encrypted.key`. However, my program only works when taking in two files that are `.pem` encoded. So my question, as of right now, is if there is any way to convert a `.key` file to `.pem`

Comment: Well we're making a rsa program in C that is supposed to read in a ciphertext that our class T.A. has private encrypted. and has also supplied his public key. Both of these are encoded in .key files so, respectively, i have two files, encrypted.key and public.key however when i try to run these and perform a public decryption (treating them as if they were PEMs) i get a RSA_Padding_check_PKCS1 block type is not 1 error

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that I find the first sentence / background of your question a bit odd. Yet, the question about the conversion is a valid one, so here goes:

The file ending .key is usually used for keys that are encoded in ASCII (PEM) or Binary (DER) format. Thus, the first thing you want to check is if the key is already in PEM format. If not, the following command convertes RSA keys from DER to PEM:

```
$ openssl rsa -inform DER -in encrypted.key -outform PEM -out now_in_PEM.key
```

If you're using DSA keys, just replace *rsa* by *dsa*.

Comment: I assumed that "encrypted" means "encrypted with AES-256" or the like.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I had solved this problem by arriving at the same code that you provided myself. I must admit, i was taking a computer security class and did not fully understand openssl at the time... but at least i do now :)